# The position of 'return x' in Python

Tags: python

I am new to coding and I want to know the reasons for difference in results depending on the position of `return x` for some random x. For example, here is a code to find out factors of a number.

```
def factors(n):
    m = []
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        if n%i==0:
            m= m + [i]
    return m
```

This code gives me the factors for any number. However, when I write the `return m` inside the `for` loop, the answer for any `factors(n)` is `[1]`:

```
def factors(n):
    m = []
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        if n%i==0:
            m= m + [i]
        return m

factors(6)
# Output: [1]
```

Can I know the reason for this discrepancy in the answers?

Comment: this isn't really about Python, this is how `return` works in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things to mention here:

first is **indentation**, python uses indentation for declaring blocks of codes so tabs / spaces are important in python (unlike C-like languages).

The second is the `return` itself, when a `return` command executes, lifetime of that function will terminate. so when you put `return` in `for` loops, the first time of iteration, it sees the return and function execution will terminate.

that's all !

Answer (score 0):

In the first code sample it will return only after the iteration through `range (1, n+1)` is over. In the second it will return during the first iteration.